# MySQL composite unique on FK's

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-error-1062

I want to implement the following constraints in mysql:

```
create table TypeMapping(
    ...
    constraint unique(server_id,type_id),

    constraint foreign key(server_id) references Server(id),

    constraint foreign key(type_id) references Type(id)
);
```

This throws a 'ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3-4' for key 'server_id'' when I issue an insert/update that would break the constraint. Is this type of constraint even possible? If so how? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly valid. Make sure you understand that the composite unique constraint will only break when you try to insert a new row in `TypeMapping`, where another row with the same `server_id` **and** `type_id` already exists.

Comment: Yes, It didn't occur to me that this is actually the expected behavior. :S